# How to fix "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT"using MySQL in node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, configuration

I just started learning how to use MySql by watching some tutorial video and I was trying to execute a query to MySQL database by using node but I'm still keep having this error: "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT mysql". Not sure if I'm missing something or what kind of code am I supposed to have.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: 'root',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3001',
    password: '******',
    database: 'employeesystem',
});

db.connect((err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
});

app.post('/create', (req, res) => {

    const name = req.body.name;
    const age = req.body.age;
    const country = req.body.country;
    const position = req.body.position;
    
    console.log(
        "\n\nName: " + name +
        "\nAge: " + age +
        "\nCountry: " + country +
        "\nPosition: " + position
    );

    db.query(
        "INSERT INTO employees (name, age, country, position) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        [name, age, country, position],
        (err, result) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Result" + result);
                res.send("Values Inserted");
            }
        }
    );
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("Your app is running well.");
})
```

Comment: Are yuo really running MySQL on port 3001 instead of the normal 3306?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a firewall blocking the port.

Comment: Yes, I'm running on port 3001. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use any port you want, it's just unusual. I was just making sure that wasn't part of the problem.

Comment: *I'm running on port 3001* - yes, YOUR APP is on port 3001 - `app.listen(3001` ... try changing `port: '3001',` in `mysql.createConnection` to point to the port that MYSQL is listenting on, not the port your code is listening on - since two things can't be listening on the same port!

Comment: Oh...do know you where can I find MySQL port? Is it on workbench?